# Navigation in a named outlet in Angular does not work. Why?

Tags: angular, router, angular-router, routerlink, router-outlet

Navigation in a named outlet in Angular does not work. Why?

Here is the error:

[image]

```
NavigationStart(id: 3, url: '/(sidebar-outlet:login/(sidebar-outlet:account-creation)//header-info-outlet:empty)')
...
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'login'
Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'login'
    at ApplyRedirects.noMatchError (router.js:4396)
```

Here is my routes setup:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: "empty", component: EmptyComponent },
  { path: "", component: HomeComponent },

  { path: "empty", component: EmptyComponent, outlet: Outlets.sidebar },
  { path: "login", component: LoginComponent, outlet: Outlets.sidebar },
  {
    path: "account-creation",
    component: CreateAccountComponent,
    outlet: Outlets.sidebar
  },
  { path: "menu", component: MainMenuComponent, outlet: Outlets.sidebar },

  { path: "empty", component: EmptyComponent, outlet: Outlets.headerInfo },
  {
    path: "header-info",
    component: HeaderInfoComponent,
    outlet: Outlets.headerInfo
  }
];
```

Here are the `Outlets`:

```
export const Outlets = {
  sidebar: "sidebar-outlet",
  headerInfo: "header-info-outlet"
};
```

Here is the `routerLink` which once is clicked produces the error:

```
[routerLink]= "[{ outlets: { 'sidebar-outlet': ['account-creation']}}]"
```

Here is the penultimate state of a router:

```
/(sidebar-outlet:login//header-info-outlet:empty)
```

Here is the expected ultimate state of a router in case the error will be fixed:

```
/(sidebar-outlet:account-creation//header-info-outlet:empty)
```

I am very confused and after searching for an answer for two days I was not able to find one. By such a `routerLink` (particularly `'sidebar-outlet': ['account-creation']`) I am expecting the route after click to be `/(sidebar-outlet:account-creation//header-info-outlet:empty)`, but it tries to become `/(sidebar-outlet:login/(sidebar-outlet:account-creation)//header-info-outlet:empty)` as we can see in the error.

How could I fix it?

**UPDATE**

Here is my `app.component.html` (only the shown below part contains `router-outlet`, there are no other places in my project`s templates where I would have used a `router-outlet`):

```
<link
  href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons&display=block"
  rel="stylesheet"
/>

<div class="mat-app-background">
  <mat-toolbar class="main-toolbar" color="primary">>
    <router-outlet name="header-info-outlet"></router-outlet>
  </mat-toolbar>

  <mat-sidenav-container>
    <mat-sidenav #sidenav 
      position="end" 
      mode="over"
      class="sidebar-container">
      <router-outlet name="sidebar-outlet"></router-outlet>
    </mat-sidenav>

    <mat-sidenav-content>
      <router-outlet></router-outlet>
      <app-footer></app-footer>
    </mat-sidenav-content>
  </mat-sidenav-container>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you show html? With those outlets....

Comment: @JohnPeters, just have added. (y)

Comment: I've never seen such complicated routing. is there a reason you aren't using simple routing? normally routing looks like this: `[routerLink]="['/login']"`

Comment: @Rick, I am not sure you understand what I am trying to implement. I have a few independent views in my app. The views are represented by different `router-outlet`\`s. I would like the navigation in the views to be independent from one another. So, the route `/login` is ok for the unnamed outlet. But the issue described in the question is solely about a named outlet navigation. And in such a case navigation to `/login` is not affecting any named outlet and that makes your comment confusing for me. Could you elaborate, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This could work for you. Create a new component named sideNavContainer. Then create another one named sideNavComponent and another SidNav2Component, break up the html so the container contains both sideNavs.,  Create a route to the container, then add 2 child routes pointing to others.

Add the container to toolbox. Any nav to children should refresh children without affecting ant thing else.

Comment: Ok. I am very grateful for your help. After reading [the documentation](https://angular.io/guide/router#nesting-routes) I am sure that I should be able to do the implementation in the way you have described it. So, I will accept your answer. :)

Comment: Oh. One very serious issue with the nested routes is that I lose the independence completely. I will be able to use the child routes in case of a fixed parent route. That is definitely not what I was looking for. Could you, please, consult me on this part?

Comment: I do not understand your point. I am sorry. Could you elaborate it, please?

Comment: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39848860/routerlink-absolute-url/51657012) question was helpful to understand your answer. Thank you. :)

Answer (score 1):

Does your template include an unnamed router-outlet? I recently faced the same troubles and for me it worked since I simply added a default router-outlet in my app-component

Comment: Yes, it does. I use the default router outlet as the main outlet. I am very grateful for your time and attention. But I am not sure that your answer solves my issue. Could you check it, please, or elaborate more on the matter?

Comment: I have an unnamed `router-outlet` and I need it for different purposes. In my case it is the main view, while I have different outlets for header and sidebar.