# Going back to previews page on Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, url, routes

I have a button that should take the user to the previews page.

I'm at `#/country/2` - 2 being an `idx`
When I click the button below it sends me to: `#/country/2/brands`, when it should be `#/brands`

```
<a [routerLink]="['brands']"><input value="sub" type="submit"></a>
```

I have imported `router` and `ActivatedRoute`. I have more routes working but not this one. Any suggestion will be welcomed.

Comment: Try to just write `routerLink='brands'` without any bracket

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What's happening right now is that it's accessing relative path. Since you are at `#/country/2/`, with `['brand']`, you will definitely be directed to `#/country/2/brands` and that is the expected behavior of your code.

Here's a very good explanation of the different routerLink parameter formats: [routerLink absolute url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39848860/routerlink-absolute-url)

If `#/brands` is from the root of your application, you simply need to use:

```
<a [routerLink]="['/brands']"><input value="sub" type="submit"></a>
```