# how to implement absolute route in angular using routerLink in angular

Tags: angular, routes, absolute-path, angular-routerlink

I have created a component to create posts, I want to make this routerLink an absolute path from app.routing, knowing that I have used this component with lazy loading

```
<a routerLink="/post/create" class="btn btn-success"><i class="fa fa-plus-square" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

If the first segment begins with /, the router will look up the route from the root of the app.
If the first segment begins with ./, or doesn't begin with a slash, the router will instead look in the children of the current activated route.
And if the first segment begins with ../, the router will go up one level.

Source : [routerLink absolute url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39848860/routerlink-absolute-url)