# routerLink to absolute root of the website ("/") while preserving all the named outlets of current URL

Tags: angular, angular-routerlink

In an Angular HTML template, I'm trying to generate a link to the welcome page (root) of my website through the following anchor tag:

```
<a [routerLink]="['/', { outlets: namedOutlets }]" [relativeTo]="null">
```

The `[relativeTo]="null"` is here to specify I don't want to generate a link relative to the current URL, but I rather want an absolute path to "/" (i.e. root of my website). The problem is, as soon as I specify '/' in `[routerLink]` it's not working anymore (e.g. I get the URL `/my/current/path/` instead of `/`), while when I put something else (like `'foobar'`) it's working correctly (I do get URL `/foobar` and not `/my/current/path/foobar`). It's also working correctly if I remove the outlets and only put `[routerLink]="['/']"`, but of course I do need those outlets.

I also tried things like:
`[routerLink]="['', { outlets: namedOutlets }]" [relativeTo]="null"`
or
`[routerLink]="['.', { outlets: namedOutlets }]" [relativeTo]="null"`
but it's also not working (e.g. I always get the URL `/my/current/path/` instead of `/`)

FYI, the `namedOutlets` array is populated in my component with the following code:

```
export class MyComponent implements OnInit {

namedOutlets: string[] = [];

constructor(private router: Router) {}

ngOnInit(): void {
  const urlTree = this.router.parseUrl(this.router.url);
  if (urlTree.fragment) {
    // Extract named outlets from URL fragments:
    const fragments = urlTree.fragment.split('/');
    fragments.forEach(fragment => {
      if (fragment.includes(':')) {
        const outletName = fragment.split(':')[0];
        if (!this.namedOutlets.includes(outletName)) {
          this.namedOutlets.push(outletName);
        }
      }
    });
  }
}
```

⇒ is there any way of forcing Angular to operate rationally and logically, in a consistent way, and to respect what it is asked to do?

Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the solution:

```
<a [routerLink]="['/', { outlets: spreadOperator({primary: null}, namedOutlets) }]">
```

Caveat:

```
  /**
   * The spread operator (`...`) can not be used from within an Angular template,
   * hence we need to call this wrap function
   * 
   * @param obj1 an object to be merged (with another object)
   * @param obj2 another object to be merged with it
   * @returns an object which is the merge of the 2 objects received in parameters
   */
  public spreadOperator(obj1, obj2): any {
    return { ...obj1, ...obj2};
  }
```

This solution was inspired to me by another stack overflow question: [routerLink absolute url](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61974700/10001863)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need to play with the list of named outlets, the solution is indeed very simple:

```
<a [routerLink]="['/', { outlets: {primary: null} }]">
```

No extra Typescript code is necessary.

(by not specifying any named outlets, Angular is going to preserve all of the named outlets found in the current URL)